# header_redirect with ampersand issue

Tags: php

I am getting the current (dynamic) page URL with:

```
$redirect = basename($_REQUEST['redirect']);
$redirect = base64_encode($redirect);
```

And that page URL might then be

```
www.domain.com/somepage?filter=1&category=1&limit=10
```

I then perform the action and want to redirect the person back to that dynamic page they were on with:

```
$redirect = base64_decode($redirect);
$output .= header_redirect($redirect);
```

But it's redirecting me to

```
www.domain.com/somepage?filter=1&amp;category=1&amp;limit=10
```

How can I fix that so that the `&amp;` becomes `&` in the redirected URL?

The `header_redirect` function is just:

```
function header_redirect ($redirect_url)
{
echo "<script>window.location.replace('" . $redirect_url . "');</script>";
}
```

Comment: Why do you even encode it?

Comment: It was an attempt to try and fix the problem. Without encoding it's also not working :(

Comment: The problem is not the encoding, it's your function. Show us your `header_redirect()` function

Comment: It's nothing special. I will add it above.

Comment: I also tried adding a `str_replace('&amp;', '&', $redirect_url);` inside the function but that doesn't work :(

Comment: Can't reproduce it. You probably don't show us your **full** and **real** code, so we can't help you

Comment: I tried to do a `var_dump($redirect)` and I received this: `string(35) "somepage?filter=&category=1&limit=1"`. So the string is correct in the variable. Is there any problem with me doing a `header_redirect($redirect)` after that I am not seeing?

Comment: Also just to add this here: `$output .= header_redirect($redirect);` Your function doesn't return anything, so it can't append anything

Comment: 1. Did you looked at it in the source code? 2. Still: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257944/header-redirect-with-ampersand-issue?noredirect=1#comment50512641_31257944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is parsing the HTML entity of the URL. Use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to reverse it.

```
function header_redirect ($redirect_url)
{
echo "<script>window.location.replace('" . html_entity_decode($redirect_url) . "');</script>";
}
```

Comment: Wow, you totally nailed it! Thanks so much for saving my sanity! :D

Comment: @user1227914 In your code there is just nothing, which would encode it! So you still don't have the source of your problem.